# How to say - thanks for clarification

Tags: formality

How you say "**thanks for clarification**" in a formal way?

For instance, is it OK to say:

> Thank you for clarifying this?

I want to include this in a formal letter about a scholarship.
This why I am trying to be as polite as it is possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Thank you for your clarification.
>
> Thank you for the clarification.
>
> Thank you for clarifying [describe the thing that was clarified].

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you mean by "in a formal way," but there's nothing wrong with:

> Thank you for clarifying.

If I were to append a word to that sentence, I might be more inclined to end with the word *that*, instead of the word *this*:

> **Me**: I don't understand why I'm not allowed to drink my bottled water next to the pool. It's a plastic bottle.
>   **Him**: Our policy is that you are not allowed to bring your own beverages to the pool. You must buy them from our concession stand.
>   **Me**: Oh. Thanks for clarifying that.

<sub>As an aside, you might want to provide more context in future questions, including why you think your suggested wording might be wrong.</sub>

Comment: In a letter regarding a scholarship, I might say: "I appreciate your clarification."